# Download database of last names

Tags: surnames, data-storage

Does anybody know if there are downloadable databases of last names per country?

E.g. this one: https://www.cbgfamilienamen.nl/nfb/achtergrond.php?actie=help contains 314.000 last names in the Netherlands, but there is no download link.

Answer (score 3):

If you have not already done so, try looking at the [Forebears](https://forebears.io/) website. It has a page of the common surnames for most countries. This is a [link to the page](https://forebears.io/netherlands/surnames) for the Netherlands and you should just be able to copy the data from there with a cut and paste.

Comment: there are 983 names in the first page. Even if I would copy and paste around 300.000 times how would i go to the 2nd page ? This is the same list as i also linked (see bottom). See this IS the question: is there instead of a top 100 list somewhere the file itself  they use .

Comment: For the US there is more to find e.g. https://www.drupal.org/project/namedb but I can not find one for the Netherlands.

Comment: I know the database is owned by https://cbg.nl/ so i think i will email them. (dutch centre for family history research)

Comment: Any update? Did they reply?